# XAML Style tag - property of property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `ResourceDictionary.xaml` I have a `<Style>` for one of my view templates. Inside, I have set a tooltip in the following way:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <templates:MyToolTipTemplate/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

How can I access the `Tooltip`'s properties (I need to set `StaysOpen`)?

Comment: You don't need a reference to tooltip in order to handle MouseOver event, you can handle it in your `MyToolTipTemplate` directly. Can you share `templates:MyToolTipTemplate` code/xaml?

Comment: Just wondering why would you want to handle MouseOver? Is there something you want to do to ToolTip, other than the default behavior of it appearing when your view is being moused over?

Comment: @Gosha my mistake - I want to set `StaysOpen`. In order to access that, I do need a reference to tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this can give you a direction for what you actually need.
Assuming that `templates:MyToolTipTemplate` is related to View (e.g its a Control):

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ToolTip StaysOpen="{Binding SomeBoolProperty,ElementName=template}">
            <templates:MyToolTipTemplate x:Name="template"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

If `templates:MyToolTipTemplate` is a ViewModel entity, you can place a relevant binding in a corresponding DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type templates:MyToolTipTemplate}">
    <ToolTip>
        <SomeControl SomeProperty="{Binding StaysOpen,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    </ToolTip>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This seems like a good direction, but it sets `SomeBoolProperty` according to `StaysOpen`, whereas what I need is a way to set `StaysOpen="True"`

Comment: You can use "invert binding" `{Binding StaysOpen,Mode=OneWayToSource...` or directly bind tooltip's property e.g. `<ToolTip StaysOpen={Binding ...`

Comment: If the first option works for you, i dont understand your problem. Simply replace Gosha's suggested binding with a *True*-Value